# Why in Laravel 4.2 last inserted id is equal to 0 when called inside another save or create?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I add a new artist

```
$artist = Artist::firstOrCreate(array(          
'name' => $artist_name
));
```

$artist->id = 132. I can see that on the callback. but

```
$paint = new Paint(array(
            'color' => Input::get('color')
            'artist_id' => $artist->id
        ));
```

I got 0 in the database... Can't understand why and how to get it

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it. Few things to update:
- add artist_id into fillables in the model
- Create a foreign key migration